# PowerBI XML Data Source from REST API Call sometimes returns "table" data type

Tags: xml, rest, powerbi, powerquery

Using PowerBI, I am calling a simple REST API that returns and XML document from a SAAS app.

In some cases, PowerBI is creating a *Table* type for certain columns where the XML may have empty values.  A very simple XML example is:

```
<Record>
  <Location>
     <id>123</id>
     <code>abc</code>
  </Location>
  <Location>
     <id>123</id>
     <code></code>      <=========  1/2 - changed this from <code/>
  </Location>
</Record>
```

Since the code attribute is empty in the second Location record, when PowerBI reads this data source it will treat the resulting *code* column as a 'Table' value.

[example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAGPy.png)

Since I have many clients that pull data from the same SAAS app and they all may/may not use a particular common field (e.g., code) it makes it difficult to create a common model that I can share with multiple clients.

I am not a Power Query Expert but I've invested a significant amount of time looking for a method to dynamically 'expand' the Table type columns in Power Query.  I've come close a few times to finding a solution that will work but have not been able to solve this problem.

There will always be one of two values in the expanded table.  It will either be text value or null.  There will never be more than those two values.

Your thoughts are greatly appreciated and a StarBucks Gift Card is available to the first person who helps me solve this issue.

There are 2 APIs that you can call to validate this behavior.
https://pbitest.proxy.beeceptor.com/   Creates the issue described.
https://pbitest2.proxy.beeceptor.com/  Works as I would expect pbitest to work.

**The PBI Query is very simple:**

```
let Source = Xml.Tables(Web.Contents("https://pbitest2.proxy.beeceptor.com/")),
Table = Source{0}[Table]
in
Table
```

Comment: My thoughts, The one which you see is a `Table` means you need to expand to new rows but it's not a table type... Power query is reading the data as its been loaded, if you know the fields that clients doesn't use then you can filter those rows, Also it would be helpful if you can show the image how power query displaying the data.

Comment: Please don't add meta-commentary to your questions. You *should* be able to delete this post yourself. If you can't, then just leave it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

That's odd that Power Query thinks an empty element expressed like `<code></code>` is a Table.

Here's an ugly query that works around that behavior.

```
let
    xml = "<Record>
  <Location>
     <id>123</id>
     <code>abc</code>
  </Location>
  <Location>
     <id>124</id>
     <code></code>     
  </Location>
</Record>",
    Source = Xml.Document(xml),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"Value"}),
    #"Expanded Value" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Value", {"Name", "Value"}, {"Name", "Value.1"}),
    #"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Expanded Value",{"Value.1"}),
    #"Expanded Value.1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns1", "Value.1", {"Name", "Value"}, {"Name", "Value"}),
    Table1 = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Value.1", "Value2",each if Value.Is([Value], type table) then Table.FirstValue([Value]) else [Value]),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Table1", "UID", each if [Name]="id" then [Value] else null),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Value"}),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Removed Columns",{"UID"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Filled Down",{{"Value2", "Value"}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Renamed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Renamed Columns"[Name]), "Name", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"UID"})
in
    #"Removed Columns1"
```

Comment: Thanks David Browne.  The challenge is that sometimes code will not appear as a table and other times it does.  This same scenario applies to every column returned for every xml payload.  Different clients use the SAAS app differently and may/may not use a particular column used in the report.  I need it to be dynamic and interrogate each column and if it's a type 'table' then expand that column.  Otherwise, ignore it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a method to change the empty attribute (<code/>) to something like <code></code> from the source system which would solve the problem.  PBI should recognize this scenario and simply create the column with the null values.

Comment: If I could wrap the Table.ExpandTableColumn() function in an "if column is a table type" condition then it would work.  It would mean a lot of manual work in the model, but it would be better than nothing.

Comment: Can you post an example of the problematic XML?

Comment: The example in my write-up will cause the issue that I'm talking about.  ID will show as text and Code will show as table.

<Record>
  <Location>
     <id>123</id>
     <code>abc</code>
  </Location>
  <Location>
     <id>123</id>
     <code/> 
  </Location>
</Record>

Comment: That's exactly the XML I pasted into my answer.  It works fine.

Comment: I agree that your solution will work IF it's known ahead of time that there will be at least one null/empty value in the xml.  However, it does not work for example if code has no null values and consequently does not create a table type.

Comment: What do you mean "does not create a table type"?  If I fill in a value for the second Location like `<code>456</code>` that query still works.

Comment: Next I would use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddler-classic)  to examine the API results to try to reproduce the issue.  I still have no idea what problem you are seeing.

Comment: David Browne...  I saved the REST API call XML that is causing issues.  I then copied the xml into Beeceptor and created a REST API endpoint that returns the exact same XML.   Here's the catch...  

When I call the Beeceptor REST API I see the CORRECT results (ie., no columns are in the 'table' type).

I suspect then that this has something to do with the Response Headers.  These are different:
strict-transport-security: max-age=16000000;includeSubDomains;preload
via:1.1 google
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block

Comment: But what do even mean by "columns are in the 'table' type"?

Comment: I'm probably not describing it correctly.  Take a look at this image.  I'm talking about how the SINGLE_ROOM_AREA column shows as a 'Table'.  The XML data being returned from my REST API call is definitely not a table.
 https://community.powerbi.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/60575i19BC1C09701C2531/image-size/large?v=v2&px=999

Comment: Looks like your API is returning multiple XML elements for SINGLE_ROOM_AREA, see updated answer.

Comment: The XML being returned from both sources is    exactly    the same.  One source works as expected, the other source does not.   The issue therefore can not be the xml payload.  PowerBI is somehow interpreting the results different -- I suspect the answer is in the headers.

Comment: Can you provide a repro of the issue?  One thing that can be troublesome in troubleshooting is that PBI will follow HTTP redirects.

Comment: A built an API that returns XML with that processing instruction and it worked fine. And the second query in the answer can turn the table into a scalar.  Fiddler will record the whole HTTP raw response, which can use to add a repro to your question.

Comment: I've created 2 mock API calls to demonstrate my challenge.   The 1st - https://pbitest.proxy.beeceptor.com/ returns XML that creates the scenario that I describe with the table.  The 2nd - https://pbitest2.proxy.beeceptor.com/ returns XML that create the data as I would expect.  The only difference between the two is the 1st has an empty code (<code></code>) and the other 2nd does not.

Comment: Please note that I also updated the original question.  It may have been better to close this and create a new one.    But I think with the help of those changes and the 2 apis provided, you can see the issue that I'm running into.

Comment: Yep.  That's odd.  See updated answer.

Comment: Great.  So we agree then that you see the same behavior.  However, your response does not solve the issue where I have 10-15 Rest API calls that return from 10-25 columns where any of those columns may/may not have this issue (depends on how SAAS client uses their data).  Ideally, there is another driver that I could use ... or ... a dynamic routine that would search for these random table entries and expand them automatically.    If you work for Microsoft, maybe you could create an issue since I believe that you now see what I'm talking about.