# PowerBI XML via a REST API GET creates 'Table' instead of values

Tags: xml, api, rest, powerbi

*This is similar to a question I created yesterday that created a lot of confusion.  I will try to close that question.  This is much clearer, I hope.*

**Overview**

Using PowerBI, I am calling a series of REST APIs that all return an XML document from a SAAS app.  I have 15 APIs that each return 10-25 columns of data.  Since this is a multi-tenant SAAS app, every customer uses the data how they choose.  I am trying to create a generic model and reports that will work for all customers regardless of how they use their data.  Seems reasonable, right?

**The Issue**

If any of the attributes in the returned XML have empty values ( ) PBI creates a 'Table' instead of the actual values. See image below for an example of what I mean by 'Table.'

Since I have no idea in advance which fields a client will/will not use, I can not create a query that works for all clients because some clients will need some tables expanded where others will not.

[Here is an example of what the issue looks like in PBI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQWWJ.png)

I'm looking for one of three possible solutions.

1. A parameter or something (e.g., alternate XML reader) to use that tells PBI not to create Tables like this.
2. A dynamic query that will identify these tables and expand them automatically with the correct names.
3. A link to a MS bug that confirms that this is a known issue.  There is no way that I'm the only one dealing with this nonsense.

**How To See The Issue For Yourself**

I've created 2 mock APIs to prove my point.  Each return the same data except the second has no empty tags.

- https://pbitest.proxy.beeceptor.com / Creates the issue
- https://pbitest2.proxy.beeceptor.com / Works as I would expect

The PBI queries are very simple:

**This one will work as expected.  No 'table' created in the returned data.**

```
let Source = Xml.Tables(Web.Contents("https://pbitest2.proxy.beeceptor.com/")),
Table = Source{0}[Table] 
in Table
```

The API Call will return this data.  Notice that all Code tags have a value.:

```
<Record>
   <Location>
      <id>123</id>
      <code>abc</code>
   </Location>
   <Location>
      <id>123</id>
      <code>def</code>
   </Location>
   <Location>
      <id>123</id>
      <code>124</code>
   </Location>
</Record>
```

**This one shows my issue. 'table' created in the returned data.**

```
let Source = Xml.Tables(Web.Contents("https://pbitest.proxy.beeceptor.com/")),
Table = Source{0}[Table] 
in Table
```

The API Call will return this data.  Notice a Code tag is empty.:

```
<Record>
   <Location>
      <id>123</id>
      <code>abc</code>
   </Location>
   <Location>
      <id>123</id>
      <code></code>     <=== Empty.  This causes the issue.
   </Location>
   <Location>
      <id>123</id>
      <code>124</code>
   </Location>
</Record>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerBI XML Data Source from REST API Call sometimes returns "table" data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70537378/powerbi-xml-data-source-from-rest-api-call-sometimes-returns-table-data-type)